# how to set message in alarm ?

Tags: android

> In alarm app, user gives input String for alarm message and sets alaram.
>   I am able to set and listen alarm.but how to display message set by user?
>    have set many times to set alarm, how   can i display respective message for that specific alarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) function in your BroadcastReceiver. It looks something like:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, ""); // Second argument is an arbitrary String tag
    wl.acquire();

    // Put YOUR code here (between WaitLocks)
    String userInputtedString = intent.getBundleExtra("UserText")
    Toast.makeText(context, userInputtedString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    wl.release();
}
```

In order to get that Bundle you have to pass in an intent extra when creating the alarm

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmNotification.class);
intent.putExtra("UserText", userInputedString);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

I just showed an example of a Toast message, but you can change that to a Notification or AlertDialog also.
Let me know if this helps.